# How can AppStore apps stop supporting ios4?

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store, appstore-approval

I have a app on App Store supporting IOS4+ device. However, I really wanted to use some new API feature in ios5 and decided to bump my base SDK to IOS5.

My questions is, what is the setting needed on iTunesConnect? Does Apple allow me to do this? What will happen to those clients running my app on IOS4? Will they just stop receiving update notification from app store?

If Apple forbidden the change, what is the best option for me? I don't want to make another app which has the same interface/functionality but with only iOS5+ device support..

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is update your project by setting the Deployment Target to your new minimum version. In this case, set the Deployment Target to iOS 5.0 or 5.1. Build and test. When your app is approved, it will only be usable on devices with the version of iOS you selected, or later.

Existing users still on iOS 4 will still be able to use their existing app. But they can't install any further updates.